# Set vertical scroll to a fixed height mat-table in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have set a height of 200px to the container of my `mat-table`. However, the table and its content does not respect the setted height. I want to add a vertical scroll to this table.
[image]

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
    <mat-table>table content</mat-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but just in case.

You might be missing `overflow: auto;` in you div styles.

Comment: I already found the answer. But I really thank you for taking your time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

you can set inline CSS And also you can use class and give these style properties in CSS file.

```
<table mat-table style="height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
// .. content
</table>
```